# Truth of OR - Logical puzzle

Tags: knowledge

This puzzle is not very difficult but it is knowledge based.

In front of you there are 4 switches. From these switches there are 4 right combinations to open the gate to the control room. You can either turn on a switch(green) or turn it off(red).

However if you try any of the wrong switch combinations, the room security has hidden weapons set to kill you.

You found the document with the title **"the key to controlling room"**.

*"the document is the hidden note so only the person who created the gate key can understand the logic and can open the gate but somehow you get it after hacking into his system."*

The document has only these letters inside it.

> it doesn't matter whatever combination you try, I am the truth of OR

Comment: 4 right combinations. That means e.g. (XXXO) (XOOO) (XXXX) (XOXO) are accepted, but all other combinations lead to the security using their weapons. Correct?

Comment: @npkllr yes it could not be any random 4 combinations, the document is the hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking the idea of @Tonks partially correct answer:

> An OR logic gate delivers the outputs 0,1,1,1 depending on the input.

Taking the hint "it doesn't matter whatever combination you try", the correct answer should be:

> the four permutations of (XOOO), and therefore (XOOO)(OXOO)(OOXO)(OOOX).

Comment: Well done, I was thinking too rigidly about this one!

Answer (score 3):

I think the truth of OR is...

> ...a programming logic gate; the 'truth' table for an OR logic gate is the following:
> `|INPUT | OUTPUT |`
> `| A | B| A OR B |`
> `| 0 | 0|    0   |`
> `| 0 | 1|    1   |`
> `| 1 | 0|    1   |`
> `| 1 | 1|    1   |`

Therefore, the answer is likely to be

> XOOO assuming Xs are 0s and Os are 1s

Comment: There are 4 correct answers to find...

Comment: Ah, I got ahead of myself here, I'll edit my answer

Comment: ROT13(sbhe pbeerpg nafjref + gur uvag "vg qbrfa'g znggre jungrire pbzovangvba lbh gel". Fb cbffvoyl gur pbeerpg pbzovangvbaf ner gur sbhe crezhgngvbaf bs (KBBB).)

Comment: @Tonks it is partially correct.